# Getting "ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor" in JBoss DB Source Configuration

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss

I'm having the same problem in both JBOSS EAP 6.3 and 7.1. And the EAP is running in Windows environment. I have 2 Data sources: one is for test, one is for stg. 
They are having very similar Connection URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin@//tst-server.tst.myapp.com:1599/testdb
jdbc:oracle:thin@//stg-server.stg.myapp.com:1521/stgdb
```

I'd been switching back and forth between these 2 in JBoss Data Sources at my local computer without any problem until one day I got this error message(ORA-12514) trying to switch to the test one. But the stg one is still working. And I have configured both in sqldeveloper and both are working as today.
 
I have read something about listener.ora and tnsnames.ora but got all confused because I couldn't find any reference for the testdb or stgdb in either listener.ora or tnsnames.ora.

Answer (score 0):

The database registers itself in the listener based on the local_listener initialization parameter.  Because it's worked in the past, it could be your test database just isn't starting up all the way and not registering itself.  Use "lsnrctl status" against your test listener to see what's registered.

Comment: what is my "test listener"? could you give me an example?<br/>

Comment: Also, the same configuration still works for my sqldeveloper. How do you explain that?

Comment: The test listener is running on tst-server.tst.myapp.com on port 1599.  There should be a tnslsnr process on there.   Working on one and not another could be a DNS problem outside of Oracle where they're hitting different IP addresses.  The registration is just the most common reason.